# cakephp lock select from table or what to do to prevent duplication

Tags: mysql, cakephp, locking

I have a data entry application created with cakephp
to save data in students table I have to generate its student-id which is equal to classname-section-studentNO (9th-B-33)
I have created private function as

```
 private function makeStudentID(){
   here I do select from classnamees, sections and students table
 }
```

but the problem is that, same numbers are being assigned to different users as I think this function is being called at the same time bcz data entry operators are many and they are entering forms ferquently
I don't know what can I do to solve this
----- EDITED --------
just consider you have `primary key` which is not `auto numbered` so next inserting number should be
`(max(id)+1)` so if at the same time 2 users send request both of them will get same id.
how to avoid this duplication?

Comment: Please add more info, like db table structure, relationships,..

Answer (score 0):

Try placing all your queries for one student in a transaction. I am not sure, but I think conflicts will be avoided that way.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html